# How can I change input gather from Text to Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

I have a form that gathers data from user inputs from textbox and then inserts it into a database.  One of the fields gathers the company from text, with txtCompanyName being the ID of the textbox.

```
string CompanyName = txtCompanyName.Text.Trim();
```

I want to change this to be a dropdown instead and the form takes that selection and insert into database. I know I need to change txtCompanyName.Text to something else...

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some introductory tutorials and examples on ASP.NET WebForms.  We don't really provide that here.  All you're asking here is how to use a `DropDownList` control.  There are many examples available for that already.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add DropDownList1.SelectedValue instead of txtCompanyName.Text